# show alert msg to share you location google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

if the user don't share the location of `google map`.show him the alert to `share your location` for all the devices. here is my code

```
if(navigator.geolocation) { 
  var latitude="";
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
      var latitude =position.coords.latitude;
       var longitude= position.coords.longitude;
      $('lati-longi').setValue(latitude+','+longitude);
        var map;
   var res=getmapbygolocation(latitude,longitude);

   })}else { alert("dsfds");  //this alert is not working
     }
```

alert message not work because the if was always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using if(navigator.geolocation){},  you checking Geolocation is supported in browser.

If you are trying to check if user has not shared location, you can use getCurrentPosition function's error callback. More info with example, you can find [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-geolocation--mobile-456)

And a working example from above link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5dw43fu/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <button id="btnInit" >Find my location</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#btnInit").click(initiate_geolocation);
});

function initiate_geolocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);
}

function handle_errors(error)
{
    switch(error.code)
    {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
        break;

        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
        break;

        case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");
        break;

        default: alert("unknown error");
        break;
    }
}

function handle_geolocation_query(position){
    alert('Lat: ' + position.coords.latitude +
          ' Lon: ' + position.coords.longitude);
}
```